# How to split maven multi modules in pipeline?

Tags: java, maven, pipeline

We do have a single repository for multiple micro services managed via maven multi modules. I'm right now trying to optimise our pipeline, by separating them as much as possible, but sadly Maven doesn't seem to support this.

I have the following maven multi module structure:

```
Backend
       - module-a
       - module-b
       - module-c
```

The pipeline I want to achieve is as following, with the artefacts from the one to the next job being defined in the arrows:

```
[Install All Dependencies]  -{SRC-WITH-.M2}-> [Test-Compile module-a] -{MODULE-A-WITH-TARGET}-> [Unit-Test module-a] -{MODULE-A-WITH-TARGET}-> [Package-Deploy module-a]
                            -{SRC-WITH-.M2}-> [Test-Compile module-b] -{MODULE-B-WITH-TARGET}-> [Unit-Test module-b] -{MODULE-B-WITH-TARGET}-> [Package-Deploy module-b]
                            -{SRC-WITH-.M2}-> [Test-Compile module-c] -{MODULE-C-WITH-TARGET}-> [Unit-Test module-c] -{MODULE-C-WITH-TARGET}-> [Package-Deploy module-c]
```

Obviously, I wouldn't ask this question if this would work as I want it to work. The problem is, that even though I did `mvn test-compile -am -pl module-a`, it doesn't work, as mvn can't resolve the sub-modules pom.xml files, without the parent pom.xml file.
And I seriously don't want to hand over the following jobs every single time the complete backend directory, as this is just time wasting for the possible speed of our pipeline. Our directory is super big and this would cost us 10 to 20 seconds each time, a new job would be triggered.

What I basically want to achieve, is a fully functioning and completely independent sub-module directory to work with, without bothering about them being technically multi-modules, once they are compiled. Sadly, I can't get this to work, as maven throws the error, that the parent's pom.xml is missing, if I only pass on a modules directory with it's target directory to the very next job. Giving the parent pom.xml as additional artefact to next job doesn't work as well, as the parent pom.xml obviously throws the error, that some sub modules are missing.

I can't really figure out what to do. Maybe someone can help me here, as I don't think that isn't something, that isn't possible. Otherwise I really need to evaluate if Mavens multi-module is something we should continue to use.

I hope for help.

Answer (score -2):

In a Maven multi-module project, you always build from the main POM.

Usually, you build the whole multi-module project with one Maven run.

Comment: I know. But as I said, I don't want to build them all in one, but treat them in the pipeline as separate and fully independent and usable modules, to parallelise them as much as possible during the pipeline run for various reasons.

Comment: Then don't use Maven multi-module. (BTW Maven multi-module also allows you to build in parallel)

Comment: So there is no other way? Better question: 

At which step is it possible to run the unit tests and integration tests, without the use of the source code? At which point at the lifecycle?

Comment: Multi-module is not meant to be separated in the way you describe. Nevertheless, it is rarely necessary to do this separation because it is fast and reliable. You can, of course, define totally separated Maven projects with a common parent POM and build your own orchestration of the resulting build.

Comment: About your other question: You do not separate tests from build. You just call `mvn clean install` or `mvn clean deploy`.

Comment: Why is that? I've been working on pipelines since three years. It's common practice to separate these steps. I've also seen several examples where people do that with maven projects. I don't agree with you on that. It may take more time speaking, but it helps to identify problems without nitpicking them.

Comment: If you separate tests, then you will do some work twice. If this is ok for you, you can do it. But this is not how Maven is designed.

Comment: No. You can forward the parts of the different maven lifecycles as artefact from one job to the next job. That's why maven is in the very opposite very easy to use and optimised for pipelines, except of the multi-module stuff.

Comment: I tried used mvn flatten:flatten too, by the way, but doesn't seem to work as well.

Comment: e.g. if you call `mvn test` and then `mvn install`, then Maven will start again from the beginning. It will check that everything is compiled and will run the tests again. So, it does no harm, but it may take time..

Comment: True, but only given that you don't use stuff like `mvn surefire:test` or `mvn failsafe:integration-test`, which in fact allows you to continue on the latest givenlifecycle, without redoing all the steps before.

Comment: But e.g. you cannot just call `mvn deploy:deploy` at the end because it will not find the artifacts unless they are created in the same Maven run. I'm just saying: Maven is designed to just call `mvn clean deploy`. You can try to divide this into steps, but then the hard work is on your side, not on Maven's. I have a multi-module project with a dozen modules, and I just call `mvn clean deploy -T4` on the parent POM and everything runs just fine.